# How to insert metadata in a field of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, metadata, keyword-argument

I want to insert a new property called "parent" to a StringField of MongoDB using the `kwargs` parameter.

Eg.: school_name is a MongoDB field and I need to create school_name.parent

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `__setattr__` method of the field. Like this:

```
school_name.__setattr__('parent', parent)
```